# How to delete backed up windows files on drive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I have a drive that has windows directory on it. Its NOT my existing windows instance but a backup. I'm trying to delete it but keep running into permissions issues. I've tried to take ownership of the files and it appears to work. However, when I try to delete the files, I get an error saying I don't have permissions, sometimes even saying I need permissions from  which is an admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what are the errors you are seeing?  Provide screenshots if necessary.  For now this is essentially a duplicate, but if your problem is definitely different from the duplicate and not solvable in that manner then edit your question and flag it to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do this from Windows, (is there a "run file browser as administrator" or similar option?) but in case a windows-only answer doesn't turn up, I'm familiar with linux:

It should be possible from a linux (Mint, Ubuntu, etc) live iso (cd/usb/dvd), mount the drive (with write permisions `rw` if it's not already, just clicking on the drive from the default file manager should work) and possibly run the file manager as root if it's still uncooperative.

You'll have to be careful to delete the right windows folder on the right drive, hopefully you've got some distinctively-named files to be absolutely sure.